# Entity Framework 6, enums

Tags: entity-framework, enums

I have an entity "Payment" in my edmx (Model-First). This entity contains int32 property "Method".

I created enum type in common assembly:

```
public enum PaymentMethod
{
    check = 100,
    credit_card = 200
}
```

In edmx designer I clicked right button on property Method and selected "Convert to enum".
I dialog I entered Enum Type Name = "PaymentMethod"   also entered External Type Name = "MyApp.Common.PaymentMethod".

Now, when I try to something like:

```
if(payment.Method == MyApp.Common.PaymentMethod.check)
```

it says 
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApp.Common.PaymentMethod' to 'Data.PaymentMethod'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

Why EF still want to use internal enum type?
edmx contans correct xml:

```
 <EnumType Name="PaymentMethod"
 a:ExternalTypeName="MyApp.Common.PaymentMethod"> xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" />
```

Comment: Is the `>` after `PaymentMethod"` a typo? It should not be there.

Comment: Is that a compile or runtime error?

Comment: @Vladimir - it looks like type of the Method property in the `payment.Method` is Data.PaymentMethod. How was the entity (payment) generated? Are you using T4 templates or something else? Have you tried regenerating your entities after the edmx was changed to include ExternalTypeName? Finally are you using POCO types (the ExternalTypeName only works for POCO entities and not entities derived from EntityObject). You may also want to take a look at a post I wrote a while ago: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/09/11/using-exisiting-enum-types-in-entity-framework-5/ (it says EF5 but applies to EF6 too)

Comment: Pawel, thank you! My entities are derived from EntityObject. So you answered to my question. Thank a lot.